# Populating Dates and Numeric Values from one table into another table

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Below is a simple list from a much longer list of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Suppose I have a supply forecast with 10 dates and Quantities from And I have a list of projects in column A1 to C10

```
Date .   Qty
5/7/2018 80
6/3/2018 100
7/9/2018 100
.....

Project . Qty Required . Qty Left     
1         10             50
2         20             30
3         50             -20 
4         20             -40
5 .       50             -90
....
```

I would like to populate two extra columns : Supply Date, Supply Qty Added.  So my table would ideally look like this.

```
Project . Qty Required . Qty Left  Supply Date .  Supply Qty Added 
1         10             50
2         20             30
3         50             60       5/7/2018        80
4         20             40
5         50             90       6/3/2018       100
```

If there were, lets say, more than 100 projects and a lot more supply dates, doing this exercise would be a little bit too manual.

I have formula for the first date and Qty(If Qty Required for Project row x is < Qty Left in Project row x-1), then bring over the Supply Date and Supply Qty Added.

but my trouble is adding the extra formula where if If Qty Required for Project row x is > Qty Left in Project row x-1, then don't do anything (or put in '').  BUT if the formula (If Qty Required for Project row x is < Qty Left in Project row x-1) is true, then use the 2nd supply date 6/3/2018.

I want my logic similar to Python where you initiate a variable (e.g. row = 0) , and then +1 once the first occurrence occurs so that it knows the grab the next row of values.

Is there a way to perform this in googlesheets, or do I have to leverage Appscripts for this type of exercise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done without a script.

One way to do this is to count the current number of non blank cells above the current row to decide which date and Qty to choose. The full formula looks something like this:

```
=IF($B2>$C1,INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&COUNTA(INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(2,ROW()-1)))-COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(2,ROW()-1)))+1),"")
```

Broken down into steps:

1. `If($B2>$C1` checks if Qty required for project row x is > Qty left in project row x-1.
2. `INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"...` this is indirectly referencing the sheet that contains the dates and quantities that we want to pull. We know it comes from column A, we just have to decide which row is the "current" row to pull from
3. `COUNTA(INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(2,ROW()-1)))-COUNTBLANK(INDIRECT("D2:D"&MAX(2,ROW()-1)))+1)` Count the number of blank cells above the current row. Using this method to account for cells with formulas.
4. `MAX(2,ROW()-1)` since we start the formula on row 2, we only want to check back for blank cells as far as row 2.

Check out [this test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1u2raMMR0VY5-O7YPT8u8OQ1CFcEienps2G9EBfl7Acc/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Very Creative. Thank you!  I applied this strategy to my larger set, and it works.